# Jenkins pipeline failed to prepare xcodeBuild step

Tags: java, ios, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created one free-style job for generating .ipa for one of my project. Its working fine and successfully generated .ipa file.

Now I want to create the same job with pipeline. So, I convert this free-style job to pipe line. But gives me error. Then I used pipeline syntax to generate script from my free-style job step by steps. But still it gives me an error.

I serched a lot for this but nothing helps. Also I tried to unlock keychain before xcode build steps start. But still same result.

It would be great if anyone help me to resolve my issue.
Thank you.

**Below is my pipeline script.**

```
node {

    stage(‘Code Fetch’) { 
        git branch: 'development', changelog: false, credentialsId: 'e7f0318c-0000-0000-0000-a5a3831b2274', poll: false, url: 'https://github.com/XXXXX/XXXXXXX.git'
    }
    stage("Installing pods") {
        sh '/usr/local/bin/pod install'
    }
    stage("Build") {
        sh '''security unlock-keychain -p apple /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
security set-keychain-settings -t 3600 -l /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db'''
        xcodeBuild appURL: '', assetPackManifestURL: '', buildDir: '', buildIpa: false, bundleID: '', bundleIDInfoPlistPath: '', cfBundleShortVersionStringValue: '', cfBundleVersionValue: '', cleanResultBundlePath: false, compileBitcode: false, configuration: 'Debug', copyProvisioningProfile: false, developmentTeamID: ‘XXXXXXXXX’, developmentTeamName: '', displayImageURL: '', fullSizeImageURL: '', generateArchive: true, ipaExportMethod: 'development', ipaName: ‘My’App, ipaOutputDirectory: 'artifacts', keychainId: '', keychainPath: '', keychainPwd: '', logfileOutputDirectory: '', provisioningProfiles: [[provisioningProfileAppId: 'com.myapp.app', provisioningProfileUUID: '955246fe-0000-0000-0000-cfa12fa742a7']], resultBundlePath: '', sdk: '', signingMethod: 'manual', symRoot: '', target: '', thinning: '', uploadBitcode: false, uploadSymbols: false, xcodeProjectFile: '', xcodeProjectPath: '', xcodeSchema: ‘MyApp’, xcodeWorkspaceFile: 'MyApp', xcodebuildArguments: ''
    }
    
}
```

**And the error I got from jenkins:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class au.com.rayh.XCodeBuilder.setKeychainPwd() expects class hudson.util.Secret but received class java.lang.String
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:492)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.injectSetters(DescribableModel.java:429)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:331)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {appURL=, assetPackManifestURL=, buildDir=, buildIpa=false, bundleID=, bundleIDInfoPlistPath=, cfBundleShortVersionStringValue=, cfBundleVersionValue=, cleanResultBundlePath=false, compileBitcode=false, configuration=Debug, copyProvisioningProfile=false, developmentTeamID=XXXXXXX, developmentTeamName=, displayImageURL=, fullSizeImageURL=, generateArchive=true, ipaExportMethod=development, ipaName=MyApp, ipaOutputDirectory=artifacts, keychainId=, keychainPath=, keychainPwd=, logfileOutputDirectory=, provisioningProfiles=[{provisioningProfileAppId=com.MyApp.app, provisioningProfileUUID=955246fe-0000-0000-0000-cfa12fa742a7}], resultBundlePath=, sdk=, signingMethod=manual, symRoot=, target=, thinning=, uploadBitcode=false, uploadSymbols=false, xcodeProjectFile=, xcodeProjectPath=, xcodeSchema=MyApp, xcodeWorkspaceFile=MyApp, xcodebuildArguments=} for au.com.rayh.XCodeBuilder
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.UninstantiatedDescribable.instantiate(UninstantiatedDescribable.java:208)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:466)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:409)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:329)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {delegate=@xcodeBuild(appURL=,assetPackManifestURL=,buildDir=,buildIpa=false,bundleID=,bundleIDInfoPlistPath=,cfBundleShortVersionStringValue=,cfBundleVersionValue=,cleanResultBundlePath=false,compileBitcode=false,configuration=Debug,copyProvisioningProfile=false,developmentTeamID=XXXXXXX,developmentTeamName=,displayImageURL=,fullSizeImageURL=,generateArchive=true,ipaExportMethod=development,ipaName=myapp,ipaOutputDirectory=artifacts,keychainId=,keychainPath=,keychainPwd=,logfileOutputDirectory=,provisioningProfiles=[{provisioningProfileAppId=com.MyApp.app, provisioningProfileUUID=955246fe-0000-0000-0000-cfa12fa742a7}],resultBundlePath=,sdk=,signingMethod=manual,symRoot=,target=,thinning=,uploadBitcode=false,uploadSymbols=false,xcodeProjectFile=,xcodeProjectPath=,xcodeSchema=MyApp,xcodeWorkspaceFile=MyApp,xcodebuildArguments=)} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:302)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeDescribable(DSL.java:499)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1172)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1172)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to prepare xcodeBuild step
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeDescribable(DSL.java:501)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:196)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1172)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:810)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1278)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1172)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:12)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor221.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor190.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:403)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:97)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:315)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:279)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Did you got solution for this pipeline script. I get error for buildDir variable in the pipeline script.

Comment: @Leena No still not getting the solution.

Comment: xcodeBuild   buildIpa: true,configuration: 'Release',  generateArchive: true, ipaExportMethod: 'development', ipaName: 'Archive', ipaOutputDirectory: 'Archive',  manualSigning: false, noConsoleLog: true, xcodeProjectPath: 'Code', xcodeSchema: 'AppSchema', xcodeWorkspaceFile: 'AppWorkspace'    @Jenish try this finally got success with this script.

Comment: @Leena I still got error. May I know which Xcode version and Jenkins version you are using ? I am using Xcode 13.4.1, Jenkins 2.319.3 and the Java version is 11.0.14

Comment: Xcode is 13.4 and Jenkins Jenkins 2.346.2 and I haven't installed Java in my system

Comment: @Leena Finally I got success to Archive and Export the build for pipeline script. I got one hint from your given script. Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you know how to define stages in pipeline where based on particular condition Archive should take place for TestFlight or exporting iPa for development purpose. Let me know if you have any idea about this.

Comment: @Leena I don't have any idea about this. Actually I created two seprate jobs for both dev and release purpose. You can refere "https://itnext.io/jenkins-tutorial-part-5-when-conditions-76e61fc8ac0e" this may be will help you.

Comment: hey thanks for the link I guess this will work will share pipeline script once its ready.

Comment: pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {
     stage ('Environment') {
         steps {
             script {

                 if ("${env.Environment}".toString().toUpperCase().equals("LIVE")) { // This will print Yes
                     echo "Yes"
                  } else {
                    echo "No"
                  }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Leena Thanks for the script. Could you please upvote my below mentioned if script found you correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Finally I got the solution and able to generate .ipa file.**

**Pipeline Script**

```
node {
   stage("Fetching repo") { 
       git branch: 'development', changelog: false, credentialsId: ‘xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx’, poll: false, url: 'YOUR-REPO-URL.git'
   }
   stage("Installing pods") {
       sh '/usr/local/bin/pod install'
   }
   stage("Archive") {
       xcodeBuild appURL: '', assetPackManifestURL: '', buildDir: '', buildIpa: true, bundleID: '', bundleIDInfoPlistPath: '', cfBundleShortVersionStringValue: '', cfBundleVersionValue: '', cleanResultBundlePath: false, compileBitcode: false, configuration: 'Debug', copyProvisioningProfile: false, developmentTeamID: ‘XXXXXXXXXX’, developmentTeamName: '', displayImageURL: '', fullSizeImageURL: '', generateArchive: true, ipaExportMethod: 'development', ipaName: ‘IPAName’, ipaOutputDirectory: 'artifacts', logfileOutputDirectory: '', provisioningProfiles: [[provisioningProfileAppId: 'com.myapp.app', provisioningProfileUUID: ‘xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx’]], resultBundlePath: '', sdk: '', signingMethod: 'manual', symRoot: '', target: '', thinning: '', uploadBitcode: false, uploadSymbols: false, xcodeProjectFile: '', xcodeProjectPath: '', xcodeSchema: ‘myapp, xcodeWorkspaceFile: ‘myapp’, xcodebuildArguments: '-destination \'generic/platform=iOS\''
   }   
   stage("Export") {
       sh 'xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ${WORKSPACE}/build/Debug-iphoneos/myappxcarchive -exportPath ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/archive -exportOptionsPlist ${WORKSPACE}/build/Debug-iphoneos/artifacts/myapp.plist'
   }
}
```